# MVC3 returning image file as byte data when using jQuery Fancybox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have built and MVC3 application with a controller (Picture) and an action method (GetImage) that returns File contents (in my case a jpeg image)

```
public FileResult GetImage(int pictureID)
    {
        return File(Server.MapPath("~/Content/pic" + pictureID + ".jpg"), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

When I access images in my views like

```
<a id="single_image"><img src="/Picture/1" /></a>
```

..I get the image displayed properly.

But when I apply jQuery Fancybox plugin to this image and click on the image, it displays the pop-up with byte[] data inside (something you would get when the file mime type is missing).

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Sorry I am unable to post any images but can email it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get your images directly using `Html.Content` in your View.

Forms

```
<a id="single_image">
    <img src="<%= Html.Content("~/Content/pic" + model.pictureID + ".jpg") %>" />
</a>
```

Razor

```
<a id="single_image">
    <img src="@Html.Content("~/Content/pic" + model.pictureID + ".jpg")" />
</a>
```

---

#### EDIT

If you're dead set on using a picture controller, then I would recommend having your `PictureController` have the `Index` action return an `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Image(int id)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Pictures");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".jpg");
    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

This will however slow down your requests over a direct .jpg file access.

Comment: Is there any way I could use "/Picture/1" instead of hardcoding the image location? I built the whole Picture Controller for this purpose.

Comment: Can I ask why you want a controller to do this rather than direct access?

Comment: Using Picture controller in my opinion will give me more control on what images to serve and what not. And also one of the things I always wanted is to hide the direct path to the image, so the directory structure is unknown to the user. Just a personal preference I guess and willing to sacrifice the request speed.
If you think the other way, let me know. I would like to hear your opinion, probably I might have missed something important.
But thanks for the answer though. really appreciate your help!

Comment: well, if the above is working for you, then you're rockin' and rollin'. PS: if the answer was helpful, an upvote to go along with the check box is cool!

Comment: I would have upvote'd it but it requires 15 reputation points. Sorry :(